# Counting groupwise category in SQL

Tags: sql, count, aggregate

I want to find a category wise count in sql server with multiple criteria
Below is the table

[image]

I want to find groupwise, checklistcode wise status count
for instance group CLT having total count for Open status and Closed status

so output should look like this

CLT     |  Clinker transport  |  CL07M1  |   Mechanical Requirments  |  4  |  1

I have tried query which is as follows,

```
    select distinct pd.GroupCode,
           pd.GroupName,
           pd.CheckListCode,
           pd.CheckListName,           
       OpenTotal =  
       CASE WHEN pd.Status = 'Open' THEN COUNT(pd.Status)               
       END,  
       ClosedTotal = 
       CASE WHEN pd.Status = 'Closed' THEN COUNT(pd.Status)             
       END
   from PunchListDetails pd
   group by pd.GroupCode,
            pd.GroupName,
            pd.CheckListCode,
            pd.CheckListName,
            pd.Status;
```

But results is not according to my needs. This above query is showing following result 
[image]

This is showing in two different lines but i want it in aggregated form as explained above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT GroupCode
      ,GroupName
      ,CheckListCode
      ,CheckListName,           
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Open' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) as OpenTotal
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Closed' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) as ClosedTotal 
FROM PunchListDetails 
GROUP BY GroupCode,GroupName,CheckListCode,CheckListName
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct, but you are (also) grouping by the status, so you'll get a different row for each status - hence you get one row that counts the open statuses and one that counts the closed ones.

Just remove `pd.Status` from the end of the `group by` clause and you should be fine:

```
select distinct pd.GroupCode,pd.GroupName,pd.CheckListCode,pd.CheckListName,           
   OpenTotal =  
   CASE WHEN pd.Status = 'Open' THEN COUNT(pd.Status)               
   END,  
   ClosedTotal = 
   CASE WHEN pd.Status = 'Closed' THEN COUNT(pd.Status)             
   END
from PunchListDetails pd
group by pd.GroupCode,pd.GroupName,pd.CheckListCode,pd.CheckListName
```